# Pivot Wide with Custom Names, Original Values in the cell

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data that is set up like the following - the CODE variable is character and needs to remain as it is because the numbers have meaning.

```
ID  CODE
1    1.0
1    0.00
1    9.99
2    40.56
3    33.54
3    0.00
```

How would I use pivot wider to rearrange it so it is like the following, where I can have 4 CODE columns and if there isn't a fourth code per ID, it is just left blank

```
ID  CODE_1  CODE_2  CODE_3  CODE_4
1    1.0      0.00   9.99    "."
2    40.56    "."     "."    "."
3    33.54     0.00   "."    "."
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can be close to what you want. You can use `tidyverse` function `complete()` to enable the level not present in your original values. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Var=factor(paste0('CODE_',row_number()),
                                          levels = paste0('CODE_',1:4),
                                          labels = paste0('CODE_',1:4),ordered = T,
                                          exclude = F)) %>%
  complete(Var = Var) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=CODE)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID CODE_1 CODE_2 CODE_3 CODE_4
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    1        0   9.99     NA
2     2   40.6     NA  NA        NA
3     3   33.5      0  NA        NA
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), CODE = c(1, 0, 
9.99, 40.56, 33.54, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

If you really want dots for missing values, you have to transform the variables to character and then assign the replace like this:

```
#Code 2
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Var=factor(paste0('CODE_',row_number()),
                                          levels = paste0('CODE_',1:4),
                                          labels = paste0('CODE_',1:4),ordered = T,
                                          exclude = F)) %>%
  complete(Var = Var) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=CODE) %>%
  mutate(across(CODE_1:CODE_4,~as.character(.))) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),'.')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID CODE_1 CODE_2 CODE_3 CODE_4
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1     1 1      0      9.99   .     
2     2 40.56  .      .      .     
3     3 33.54  0      .      .
```

Comment: Thank you, now the part where you reference var, what is that referring to ? is that a variable name or some kind of function

Comment: @user13203033 Variable name which contains the names for the new columns. in this case the CODE_1,...,CODE_4 I hope that was clear enough. Let me know if it wasn't

Comment: It works, however I get per ID an additional row, where the ID is the same, but all the other rows are NA. So if ID was 2 then I would have two columns where ID = 2, but the second one has NA in all fields.

Comment: @user13203033 Maybe is the data that is creating the empty rows. Are you trying with new data of the data in this example?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID ~ paste0("CODE_", rowid(ID)), value.var = 'CODE')
#   ID CODE_1 CODE_2 CODE_3
#1:  1   1.00      0   9.99
#2:  2  40.56     NA     NA
#3:  3  33.54      0     NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), CODE = c(1, 0, 
9.99, 40.56, 33.54, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```